# How to check value of radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Everything else I've tried hasn't worked. I just want a conditional to check if one of the radios are selected, and one will always be selected. I need to know which one is selected.

`<label for="starting">Starting Player:</label>
<input type="radio" name="starting" value="1" checked>P1
<input type="radio" name="starting" value="2" id="startingPlayer">P2`
`document.getElementById("startingPlayer").checked==true`

Either always produces true or false. Any ways to get around this?

Comment: You can use a selector: `document.querySelector('[name="starting"]:checked')`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the set of buttons and check the `.checked` property.

You can do this whenever you need to. Here, I'm doing it on a button click.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
var btnCheck = document.querySelector("button");
btnCheck.addEventListener("click", checkSelected);

function checkSelected(){
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
    if(buttons[i].checked){
      console.clear();
      console.log("The selected radio button has a value of: " + buttons[i].value);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="starting">Starting Player:</label>
<input type="radio" name="starting" value="1" checked>P1
<input type="radio" name="starting" value="2" id="startingPlayer">P2 
<button>Get Selected Button Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ES6** solution. Use `Array#forEach` to bind `change` event to each radio button and log the value of the actually selected button.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByName('starting');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('change', function() {
  Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.checked ? console.log(v.getAttribute('value')) : null)
}))
```

```html
<label for="starting">Starting Player:</label>
<input type="radio" name="starting" value="1" checked>P1
<input type="radio" name="starting" value="2" id="startingPlayer">P2
```

Comment: This will get every input that is checked, including all radio button sets and checkboxes. It would be better to start with a *name* selector, either `getElementsByName('starting')` or `querySelectorAll('[name="starting"]')`

Comment: @RobG Good idea.

Answer (score -1):

`var player= document.forms.MyForm.starting.value;` can be the solution..